# Add repository into Apache Servicemix 4.4.1

Tags: jdbc, osgi, driver, apache-servicemix

How can I add a repository into Apache Servicemix 4.4.1?

I must install Spring JDBC Template and PostgreSQL drivers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked my colleague and she found the solution!

First, the Spring jdbc library is already in the service mix, I didn't noticed the Spring-jdbc library earlier.

For PostgreSQL there are some steps:

1. Create a new xml file like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <features>
       <feature name="jdbc-driver">
           <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp/1.4_2</bundle>
           <bundle>mvn:org.postgresql/com.springsource.org.postgresql.jdbc4/8.3.604</bundle>
       </feature>
   </features>
   ```
2. Open the servicemix command console and type:

   ```
   features:addUrl file:[file's path]
   ```
3. Finally

   ```
   features:install jdbc-driver
   ```